# How to check if input is empty and apply class to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I want to recreate this effect as below (Hoshi):
https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/

I have looked up this JS and google a bit of validators but just can not understand how to make this when i entered text into input, the label stays there. In my case when i entered text and left input, label moves back down.

Comment: where is your code??

Answer (score 0):

I've created a minimal example how this could be done.
See my comments in the code to understand how it works.

```js
$("#input").focus(function() {
  // If you enter the input

  $("#test").animate({ // Animate the text to the top
    top: "20px",
  }, 200, function() {});

}).blur(function() {
  // If you left the input

  if ($(this).val() == "") { // Only if the input is empty

    $("#test").animate({ // Animate the text back into the input
      top: "50px",
    }, 200, function() {});
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#test {
  top: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <input type="text" id="input"><span id="test">Test</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be easily achieved without a single line of JavaScript with pure CSS. I added a snippet below to demonstrate the basic idea. I'm using the [required attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) for inputs in combination with the [:valid css selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_valid.asp) to check if the input is empty.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

label > span {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: text;
  left: 2px;
  top: 1px;
  transition: top .2s ease;
  color: #3a3a3a;
}

label > input:focus + span,
label > input:valid + span{
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input required type="text" />
  <span>Surname</span>
</label>
```